# How to set style for all elements with a specified class name in sencha

Tags: css, dom, sencha-touch

I'm using Sencha for the first time.  Previously, I've been using jquery.   What is the Sencha equivalent for the following jquery command?

```
$('.card').css('background-image', 'url(bg.jpg)');
```

In other words, I want to find all elements with the class name `card`, then I want to add a `background-image:url(bg.jpg)` to them.

Comment: why don't you add the `background-image: url(bg.jpg);` to your css file for the `card` class?

Comment: because i need to programmatically assign the image which is stored as a base64encoded string in HTML5's localStorage.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This should do it:

```
Ext.select('.card').setStyle('background-image', 'url(bg.jpg)');
```